# Moving a Project to Angular Package Format

Tags: javascript, angular, git, typescript, github

I have a project:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fireflysemantics/slice

I need to move it to the Angular package format.  The reason is this:

> node_modules/@fireflysemantics/slice/index.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
>   The missing file seems to be part of a third party library. TS files in published libraries are often a sign of a badly packaged library. Please open an issue in the library repository to alert its author and ask them to package the library using the [Angular Package Format](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CZC2rcpxffTDfRDs6p1cfbmKNLA6x5O-NtkJglDaBVs/preview).

I think the right way to do this is to create a new empty branch with:

```
git checkout --orphan angular-package-format
//clear the working directory
git rm --cached -r .
```

Then just generate a new Angular library project into this new branch:

```
ng new angular-package-format --create-application=false
cd angular-package-format
ng generate library slice
```

Then commit and publish that library as noted here:

https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/creating-an-angular-9-npm-library-1a658ecfa3dc

I think this is probably the right way to go about it, but wanted to check with everyone else as this is the first time I'm attempting this.  Is there anything you would change WRT the steps I mentioned?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. Your project isn't an Angular library, and doesn't even have a dependency for Angular. So unless you're planning on adding Angular imports to your source code, then there is no benefit in using an Angular library. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I was actually thinking the same thing, until I got the compilation error mentioned in the question ... just updated it.  Angular does a really nice job of supporting all the package formats with a very simple process, so I figured I might as well just move the whole thing over.  The medium article I wrote and linked shows the steps.  I'm very impressed with how easy Angular has made this.  Takes the thinking out of it ...

Comment: I get it. It's hard to build a TS project as a lib for npm there isn't really a standard way, and the Angular library gives you an easy to use CLI to compile it. I ran into the same issue my library, and it was an Angular lib originally but then I couldn't use it with a React project later. So that's the down side, but if you know it will always be for an Angular project, then go for it. You're welcome to copy my project, and then just replace the src content with your own library. https://github.com/reactgular/observables

Comment: Thanks for sharing!  I'll check it out!  IIUC with the way Angular does it now it will still work with all package formats.  For example I recently created this project: https://github.com/fireflysemantics/angular-stripe-service/tree/master/projects/angular-stripe-service-lib/src/lib

Comment: When I compile that Angular automatically creates all the popular package formats (UMD, fesm5, esm5, esm2015, fesm2015), so IIUC it should now work in essentially all environments.

Comment: That is true, but I tried that before and it didn't seem worth it. So now I build my library for just ES5, and then users of the library use something like Babel to compile my library to their different targets. This is something that Angular does automatically. This will work if you don't bundle the output of the library so the JS file uses native ES5 modules, and then TypeScript imports them and Babels them to different targets. I do have a UMD because I thought I would use my library on stackblitz for examples, but I never did. I don't think anyone needs it.

Comment: Honestly, it is just easier to use the Angular CLI. I wish we had a standard CLI for people who just want to share TypeScript libraries.

Comment: It's really easy to do this now.  See: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/creating-an-angular-9-npm-library-1a658ecfa3dc

Comment: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/unit-testing-angular-with-jest-b65888ff33f6

Comment: I think the end result will be far superior to what we can do with just ES5 packaging with @types ... we don't really have to worry about this anymore ... Angular takes care of it all ...

Comment: I think all we need to do in additional to the steps I mentioned in the blog is add a license and update package.json for the library with the location of the github repository etc.  That did not get auto generated when I wrote the Stripe service.

Comment: I know of many React developers who will be unhappy running Angular to compile a library they use. While the output is usable for them. It's a political thing. So it's better if my library is neutral about frameworks, but I wish we had something like it that was just for building generic libraries.

Comment: I have a friend that thinks the exact same way :).  I think once they see the process and understand it they will see that there are a lot of benefits to this including making the package more universally accessible for both Typescript and normal javascript users and the process is completely streamlined so that we don't need to think about the steps anymore really ... Angular just does it all.  Also when Angular generates a library that library is free of Angular dependencies.  Any other framework can use that library.

Comment: I think it's only a small matter of time before someone extracts the process out of Angular and just makes it into something that everyone should do when making generic NPM packages.

Comment: Another thing is that Angular corrects a lot of possible mistakes that we might otherwise make like this one:   'dependencies'.
ERROR: Dependency @fireflysemantics/collections must be explicitly whitelisted.
An unhandled exception occurred: Dependency @fireflysemantics/collections must be explicitly whitelisted.
See "/tmp/ng-7mRASz/angular-errors.log" for further details.

Comment: WARNING: Distributing npm packages with 'dependencies' is not recommended. Please consider adding @fireflysemantics/collections to 'peerDependencies' or remove it from 'dependencies'.

Comment: I think it also strips the "scripts" from the `package.json` file for security reasons, but if I remember correctly that `npm publish` now does this also. There are downsides to using Angular, because it doesn't handle asset files or let you build a library that also has a runnable script.

Comment: Another thing that I'm fairly delighted with is that before I had about 10 dev dependencies for performing the `dist` compilation, and now all that goes away essentially.  So I get a superior package with a lot less process overhead.  Remembering all these things was a massive PITA .... how to setup types compilation, resolving paths properly, installing the right plugins to resolve paths, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: One more article on how to setup Jest properly for library testing: https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/unit-testing-your-angular-library-project-with-jest-42429a8716eb